# R combine cell content if condition true

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

I want to combine the content of two cells if several conditions are true.

I have the follwoing dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(page = c("a1","a1","a2","a2","a3"),
                 keyword = c("a,b,c", "a,b,c,d", "d,e,f","g","a"))
```

The conditions in pseudo code:

```
if some cells of column page are equal (e.g. a1 and a2 appear two times)
then combine the content of column keyword and delete duplicate content.
```

This means in the end I need a dataframe, which looks like this:

```
page  keyword
  a1  a,b,c,d
  a2  d,e,f,g 
  a3  a
```

I already tried different approaches but didnt receive the correct result. Does anybody has an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `data.table` you could do

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, .(unlist(strsplit(keyword, split = ","))), by = page
   ][, .(keyword = toString(unique(V1))), by = page]
#   page    keyword
#1:   a1 a, b, c, d
#2:   a2 d, e, f, g
#3:   a3          a
```

---

And here is a `tidyr` and `dplyr` option.

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  separate_rows(keyword, sep = ",") %>% 
  group_by(page) %>% 
  summarise(keyord = toString(unique(keyword)))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  page  keyord    
#  <chr> <chr>     
#1 a1    a, b, c, d
#2 a2    d, e, f, g
#3 a3    a
```

Comment: Very nice and simple solution! Thank you very much!